# Parsing an input-string with different quotes via RegEx

Tags: regex, powershell, parsing

I need to convert an input-string with multipe words into a string-array via Powershell.
Words can be separated by multiple spaces and/or linebreaks.
Each word can be escaped by a single quote or a double quote.
Some words may start with a hashtag - in that case any quoting appears after that hashtag.

Here a code sample of a possible input and the expected result:

```
$inputString = @"
  test1
  #custom1
  #"custom2"           #'custom3'
  #"custom ""four"""   #'custom ''five'''
  test2 "test3" 'test4'
"@

$result = @(
    'test1'
    '#custom1'
    '"#custom2"'
    "#'custom3'"
    '#"custom ""four"""'   
    "#'custom ''five'''"
    'test2' 
    '"test3"' 
    "'test4'"
)
```

Is there any solution to do this via a clever RegEx-expression? Or does someone have a parser-snippet/function to start with?

Comment: It's going to be a nightmare to handle the `''`/`""` escape sequences with regex, you'd be better off writing a parser by hand (read the string one character at a time and decided whether it's a continuation of the previous token or not)

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback. Would it be possible to mis-use the convertFrom-CSV servlet?

Comment: No, it'll expect the delimiter to be uniform and it'll interpret anything starting with `#` as comment/metadata. You'll need to write your own

Comment: Are the hashtags allowed to appear inside a string? If not, replacing them would make this task a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming you fully control or implicitly trust the input string**, you can use the following approach, which relies on [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression), which [should normally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375):

**Assumptions** made:

- `#` only appears at the *start* of embedded strings.
- No embedded string contains newlines itself.

```
$inputString = @"
  test1
  #custom1
  #"custom2"           #'custom3'
  #"custom ""four"""   #'custom ''five'''
  test2 "test3" 'test4'
"@

$embeddedStrings = Invoke-Expression @"
Write-Output $($inputString -replace '\r?\n', ' ' -replace '#', '`#')
"@
```

*Caveat:* The *outer* quoting around the individual strings is *lost* in the process and the *embedded, escaped* quotes are *unescaped*; outputting `$embeddedString` yields:

```
test1
#custom1
#custom2
#custom3
#custom "four"
#custom 'five'
test2
test3
test4
```

The approach relies on the fact that your embedded strings use PowerShell's quoting and quote-escaping rules; the only problems are the leading `#` characters, which are escaped as `` `# `` above.
By replacing the embedded newlines (`\r?\n`) with spaces, the result can be passed as a list of positional arguments to [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output), inside a string that is then evaluated with `Invoke-Expression`, which makes `Write-Output` output the parsed arguments one by one, captured as an array in variable `$embeddedStrings`.

Comment: that assumptions are fulfilled in the given scenario.

Comment: As for down-voting questions, @Carsten: I think that some users frown at a perceived lack of effort on the part of the asker. To me, while an attempted solution as part of the question helps, it isn't a requirement, as long as the question has a clear description of the problem.

Comment: I agree, its terrible to get a negative score at all for a question. I think the root cause is the fact, that for RegEx you cannot create a sample code-snippet here. Either it works or it fails.